# Docker Login not working

Tags: login, docker

I'm unable to download images from docker hub as the client reports I'm not logged albeit I'm. Example:

```
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.
Username: ******
Password: ****
Login Succeeded
mordor darkflow # NV_GPU=1 nvidia-docker run --rm -ti device-query
Unable to find image 'device-query:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for device-query, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Is the image `device-query:latest` supposed to be pulled from a repository within the registry you logged into?  `hub.docker.com` does not appear to have a `device-query:latest` image so it seems you need to specify which repository to pull from from, i.e. `repository/device-query:latest`

Comment: You are right! I needed to point to my internal repo!